# sql nested selects

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and I understand what's going on here in general, but I can't explain it in detail.
I thought ,

The lookupweekid value taken from the lookupday table is decreased by -1 and assigned to the lookupweekid of the t2 table. Where t1.lookupweekid=t2.lookupweekid and t1.weekdaynumber=1. start_of_week is imported into table t3.

What do you think about my thought, is it true?

```
(select dateoftransaction
 from lookupday t1,
      (select lookupweekid-1 from lookupday 
       where dateoftransaction = date) t2 (lookupweekid)
 where t1.lookupweekid=t2.lookupweekid
   and t1.weekdaynumber=1) t3 (start_of_week)
```

Comment: Somewhat poorly written code. All columns should to be qualified to make it understandable. And explicit JOINS should be used.

Comment: i know and i didn't write it. i just want to understand this

Comment: is this a particular implementation of sql, e.g. MySQL?  My guess is maybe 'date' is going to be a keyword for 'current date'.  What if you try something like select dateoftransaction from lookupday 
       where dateoftransaction = date  --what do you get then?  (as experiment)

Comment: = date is current date, it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's calculating the start of the previous week.

Maybe the t3 sub-query can also be written like this:

```
select dateoftransaction
from lookupday
where lookupweekid in (select lookupweekid - 1
                       from lookupday 
                       where dateoftransaction = current_date)
  and weekdaynumber = 1
```